# Unclear restriction about noptr-new-declartor

Tags: c++, arrays, allocation

```
noptr-new-declarator:
    [ expression ] attribute-specifier-seq_opt
    noptr-new-declarator [ constant-expression ] attribute-specifier-seq_opt
```

It is unclear why does in the latter case of allowed `noptr-new-declarator` in a square brackets exactly **constant-expression** is used.

I don't see something critical if we allow to allocate something like

```
int n = 10;
float *fp = new float[5][n];
```

Comment: I think it is for the sake of consistency, `float[5][n]` should define a type, and var-arrays are not yet supported by the standard, that is, you cannot (yet) define `float array[5][n]` if `n` is not `const` or `constexpr` (or `#defined`)

Comment: @vsoftco But `float[n][5]` is permitted by the Standard in the case. Moreover, as I've understood, it is not a var-array. It is just dynamically created array.

Comment: so.cpp:27:14: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'x' [-Wvla] `float x[n][5];`. Compile with `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra` and you'll get a warning. So because you cannot (officially) declare static variable length arrays, you are not allowed to use your construction, again probably just for consistency reasons.

Comment: `float[n][5]` is a bunch of `float[5]`, size known at compile time. `float[5][n]` is a bunch of `float[n]`. How would you compute `f+1` at compile time ?

Comment: @Johan new-expression define an object with **dynamic** storage duration. Why do we need to compute it exactly at compile time?

Comment: Because `new float[2][2]` is not a `float*` but a `float*[2]` and so the variable where it is stored can access the second element of the first dimension by using `f + 1`. Using size which have to be known at compile time.

Comment: @Johan So what is the difference between `float[2][2]` and `float[10][2]`?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv No type difference, if we're speeking of `new float[2][2]` compared to `new float[10][2]`. Both can be stored into a `float*[2]` pointer but one is overrun by `f + 2` whereas the other need `f + 10`to overrun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compile :

```
float* f = new float[2][2];
```

You have the following error:

> cannot convert ‘float (*)[2]’ to ‘float*’ in initialization

It explains that `new float[2][2]` generates a bunch of `float*[2]` and not just pointer on float. The type of the variable you use to store the result have to know its size at compile time to allow access to array elements.

It's easy to see that the size depends of the non-first array size if you're doing a bit of pointer arithmetic ([online code](http://ideone.com/q3viMA)):

```
auto f1 = new float[2][10]; 
std::cout << "F1[0]: " << f1[0] << std::endl;
std::cout << "F1[1]: " << f1[1] << std::endl;
std::cout << "F1[1] - F1[0] : " << f1[1] - f1[0] << std::endl;

auto f2 = new float[2][5];  
std::cout << "F2[0]: " << f2[0] << std::endl;
std::cout << "F2[1]: " << f2[1] << std::endl;
std::cout << "F2[1] - F2[0] : " << f2[1] - f2[0] << std::endl;

auto f3 = new float[5][5];  
std::cout << "F3[0]: " << f3[0] << std::endl;
std::cout << "F3[1]: " << f3[1] << std::endl;
std::cout << "F3[1] - F3[0] : " << f3[1] - f3[0] << std::endl;
```

This code outputs:

```
F1[0]: 0x600010480
F1[1]: 0x6000104a8
F1[1] - F1[0] : 10
F2[0]: 0x600048580
F2[1]: 0x600048594
F2[1] - F2[0] : 5
F3[0]: 0x6000485b0
F3[1]: 0x6000485c4
F3[1] - F3[0] : 5
```

All those sizes need to be computed at compile time, which make constexpr mandatory.